# How to control the speed of this animated counter?

Tags: reactjs

I made a very simple animated counter using effect hooks and a `setTimeout`. It works fine so far except for the speed.

If there are multiple counters on the same page, I would like that they all finish their animation at the same time regardless of the final count. I though that using the calculation `speed / count` on the timeout would work but it just seems random.

```
const Counter = ({ count, speed }) => {
    const timeout = useRef();
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(counter > 0) {
            setCounter(0);
            timeout.current = null;
        }
    }, [count]);
    
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if(counter < count) {
            timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
                setCounter(prev => prev + 1)
            }, speed / count);
        }
        
        return () => {
            if(timeout.current) clearTimeout(timeout.current);
        }
    });
    
    return (
        <div id="counter">
            {Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(counter)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I think it's because of the re-render times that can't be predicted, but I'm not sure. Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Arkellys/pen/yLKRzaK) with controls.

**How can I control the speed of the counter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

The counter was not respecting the speed simply because I was trying to increment the counter one by one. It means that if my count is `10000` and the speed `3000`, I ask to make 10,000 renders in 3 seconds, which is impossible. So the counter was just going at max speed.

To fix this, I store the starting time in a ref, and then make a calculation to know what should be the current number depending on the time elapsed. I also use a fixed time of `50` for the timeout. I guess I could make this a prop to regulate the number of times it rerender.

```
const Counter = ({ count, speed }) => {
    const timer = useRef({ start: Date.now() });
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(counter > 0) {
            timer.current.start = Date.now();
            setCounter(0);
        }
    }, [count]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(counter < count) {
            const timeElapsed  = Date.now() - timer.current.start;
            const timePerNum = speed / count;   
            const currentCount = Math.round(timeElapsed / timePerNum);
            
            let newCount = currentCount + 1;
            if(newCount > count) newCount = count;
                
            setTimeout(() => {
                setCounter(newCount)
            }, 50);
        }
    });

    
    return (
        <div id="counter">
            {Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(counter)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I've updated the CodePen with the fixes.